# How to catch lifecycle events with ProcessLifecycleOwner?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components

I am trying to (at least partially) determine when an application gets closed by the user to release some connections, etc. To do this, I am using the `ProcessLifecycleOwner` with my application class implementing `LifecycleObserver`. Despite taking the starting code from tutorials and other helpful articles, it does not seem to detect any lifecycle events.

Most of the code came from [this example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v0.2/General/ProcessLifecycle/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/LifecycleApplication.java).

My application class:

```
public class App extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    public void created() {
        Log.d("SampleLifeCycle", "ON_CREATE");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void started() {
        Log.d("SampleLifeCycle", "ON_START");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void resumed() {
        Log.d("SampleLifeCycle", "ON_RESUME");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void paused() {
        Log.d("SampleLifeCycle", "ON_PAUSE");
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void stopped() {
        Log.d("SampleLifeCycle", "ON_STOP");
    }
}
```

The dependency in Gradle

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
}
```

So far, this code has not logged a single event of any sort, whether the app is entering the foreground or the background.

**EDIT**

Note: You NEED to declare your application in the Manifest for anything to work in your custom application class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the corresponding annotation processor to pay attention to those annotations:

```
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
```

Or, enable Java 8 support, and switch to `DefaultLifecycleObserver`.

Comment: @AshesToAshes: Yes, alongside your `implementation` statement from above.

Comment: Turns out the real issue was I was missing the application name declaration in the Manifest. I will accept your answer as I was missing that statement in the file. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0-beta01