# How can an Android application ignore broadcast messages from other applications?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, barcode-scanner

I have two Android applications `A1` and `A2`.

Both applications are started and presenting respectively an activity `B1` and `B2` on the screen.

Application `A1` is in foreground. Application `A2` is in background.

Both are using the device's barcode reader.
Activities `B1` and `B2` are capable of receiving broadcast messages from the barcode reader.

The applications use the Java package `android.content.BroadcastReceiver`.

Here is what I do:

- In the first application `A1`, I scan a barcode.
- The barcode value is printed in a view on the screen `B1` in application `A1`.
- **My problem is** that it is also printed in a view on the screen `B2` in the second application `A2`.

When I scanned the barcode in the application `A1`, it also entered the "onReceive()" method in the application `A2`. The second application received the broadcast messages from the first application.

**My question is**: how can I make the second application `A2` ignore the broadcast messages from other applications?

Please ask for more details if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you write A2? If so, you need to decide what your rule is. If the rule is "do not scan barcodes in the background", adjust your code to disable or unregister your receiver when you are in the background (e.g., using `ProcessLifecycleOwner`). If the rule is "do not scan barcodes while A1 is around", have A1 tell A2 what to do by some form of IPC (broadcast, service, etc.).

Comment: Hi. I'm writing A2. I cannot change A1's code.

Comment: Then your rule will need to be "do not scan barcodes in the background", I guess.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. That solves my problem. I used this thread for implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780722/how-to-catch-lifecycle-events-with-processlifecycleowner

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what the trigger is for A2 to move from normal operation to a mode where it ignores broadcasts. Since you did not write A1, one possible trigger is "A2 moves to the background". For that, you can use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`, to find out when your entire app moves between foreground and background UI states. Then, when you are in the background, you can do something to ignore the barcode events, such as:

- Unregister the receiver, if you registered it via `registerReceiver()` (which I assume is the case)
- Disable the receiver, if you registered it in the manifest
- Keep track of your foreground/background state in some flag, and have your receiver use that flag to decide whether to process or ignore the barcode broadcast
- Etc.